# How to add a files to site asset inside the sub sites?

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, visual-studio, module

I need to add some files inside the Site collection and subsite site asset Library, So I tried module to achieve this, It's working for the site collection, but It's not working for Subsites, Please suggest me some idea to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add files via module to site collection and at subsite level also, Assuming you would have a feature created which includes this module, Mostly you would have kept the Scope of feature as Site, you need to change it to Web. This way this feature will be displayed at subsite level(not in site collection feature). once you activate this, your files will move to required library as it worked at site collection.